# Convert 2D array from PHP into JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, initialization

Imagine that I have 2D array in PHP like this:

```
<?php
$db = array(
    "1" => array(
         "1" => "aaa",
         "2" => "bbb",
         "3" => "ccc"
    ),
    "2" => array(
         "1" => "ddd",
         "2" => "eee"
    ),
    "3" => array(
         "1" => "fff",
         "2" => "ggg",
         "3" => "hhh"
    )
);
?>
```

And I would like to convert it to JS, yes I can do something like:

```
var db = new Array(3);
db[1][1] = "aaa";
db[1][2] = "bbb";
db[1][3] = "ccc";
db[2][1] = "ddd";
db[2][2] = "eee";
db[3][1] = "fff";
db[3][2] = "ggg";
db[3][3] = "hhh";
```

Bit this initialization of array in JS is ugly, is there better way to initialize it like in PHP?

Comment: If you have it in PHP and want to convert (or transfer) it to Javascript you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `json_encode` the array

**php**

```
$db = array(
"1" => array(
     "1" => "aaa",
     "2" => "bbb",
     "3" => "ccc"
),
"2" => array(
     "1" => "ddd",
     "2" => "eee"
),
"3" => array(
     "1" => "fff",
     "2" => "ggg",
     "3" => "hhh"
)
);
echo json_encode($db);
```

**output**

```
 {"1":{"1":"aaa","2":"bbb","3":"ccc"},"2":{"1":"ddd","2":"eee"},
 "3": {"1":"fff","2":"ggg","3":"hhh"}}
```

**Javascript**

```
 var arr = {"1":{"1":"aaa","2":"bbb","3":"ccc"},"2":{"1":"ddd","2":"eee"},
 "3": {"1":"fff","2":"ggg","3":"hhh"}};
```

**Output accessing some index**

```
 arr[1][1] = aaa
 arr[1][3] = ccc
 arr[2][2] = eee
```

Answer (score 1):

js can also initialize array in one line :

```
var db = [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["ddd", "eee", "fff"], ["ggg", "hhh", "iii"]]
```

it is actually very rare to see the `new Array()` notation (I had forgotten about it until reading you question)

**Bonus :** this way of declaring arrays is also correct in php

```
$db = [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["ddd", "eee", "fff"], ["ggg", "hhh", "iii"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP array looks like it's an associative array of associative arrays: a great way to have named keys that point to your values.

In JS, arrays are numerically indexed from zero, and the data type to use for named associative key => value pairs is the JS object.

Here are two approaches. Example #1 uses the array syntax, if the index value does not need to be named explicitly. Example #2 demonstrates using a JS object, in case you need your keys to be named with a string.

```
var example1 = [
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    ['ddd', 'eee'],
    ['fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']
];


var example2 = {
    "1": {
        "1": "aaa",
        "2": "bbb",
        "3": "ccc"
    },            
    "2": {
        "1": "ddd",
        "2": "eee"
    },
    "3": {
        "1": "fff",
        "2": "ggg",
        "3": "hhh"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a PHP array on JS Script, you can declare it on PHP

```
<?php 
  $db = array(
  "1" => array(
      "1" => "aaa",
      "2" => "bbb",
      "3" => "ccc"
  ),
  "2" => array(
      "1" => "ddd",
      "2" => "eee"
  ),
  "3" => array(
      "1" => "fff",
      "2" => "ggg",
      "3" => "hhh"
  )
); 
?>
```

then just "echo" it on JS array declaration.

```
<script>
    var myJsObject = <?= json_encode($db) ?>; 
</script>
```

Otherwise if your question is about coding syle

```
<script> 
 var myJsObject = { 
              "1" : { 
                  "1" : "aaa", 
                  "2": "bbb", 
                  "3" : "ccc"
              }, 
              "2" : { 
                  "1" : "dd", 
                  "2": "ee"
               }
             }; 
</script>
```

Note that PHP Associative Arrays are Objects if represented in JS, not arrays. You can access them as array too.